# Fill up container with nav list items

Tags: html, css, less

a front-end beginner here. I was trying to build this page and I am having trouble with aligning the navbar items with the rest of the components.

This is how it currently looks on my page.
[image]

and this is how I would like to have it.
[image]

I have made sure that my containers are all same size with specific width>
[image]

My Code

```
<section class="navigation-bar">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-single-column">
                        <nav class="topnav navbar" id="myTopnav">
                            <ul class="navbar-items">
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#Fashion">Fashion</a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#Electronics">Electronics</a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#art">Collectibles & Art</a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#home">Home & Garden </a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#sports">Sporting</a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#motors">Motors</a></li>
                                <li class="inline-block"><a href="#deals">Daily Deals</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </section>
```

css

```
.navigation-bar {
        position: relative;
        top: -3em;
    }


    .navbar,
    .navbar-items,
    .navbar-items > li {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar-items {
        padding: 0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-items > li {
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

I tried using flex, paddings, margins and many other ways of adjusting the space between elements but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `display: table;` only for tables.

You can achive desired layout with flexbox:

```
.navbar-items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vodkg1jp/1/